# How to upload bulk products in Magento1.9

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to know that How I can upload 5000+ items with :-

**Item Sku, Item Url, Item Name, Item Brand Name, Main Category Name, Category Name, Sub-Category Name, Item Unit, Item Price, Item Image.**

No other Fields because in Magento admin mentioned lot's of fields. I tried Magento import export but every time it's not good for us doing this way.

I have csv file and this csv file will be daily update.

Any third party extension or any other way which one make more easy for us ??

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Magmi.  Just download it and unzip it into magento root under /magmi .  Navigate to magmi.php.  The initial user name is magmi and the password is magmi.  After the first login it is your magento admin username and password.  I've used it to import up to 75k products and many attributes.  I would recommend using a video tutorial or something to set it up correctly.

Comment: Can you share url and video link How I can use it ??

Comment: It's not the easiest web app to set up but well worth the effort.

Comment: it also has a command line option which is capable of more products.  I used it for 75k+ products.